# odoo: it's not possible to make a line invisible on one2many?

Tags: odoo, invisible, one2many

I am traying to make some lines (one2many stock.move) invisble based on a field `filtre_project` (in stock.picking).
 I tried using domain as:

```
<field name="move_lines" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="domain">[('project_id','in',filtre_project and filtre_project[0] and filtre_project[0][2])]
</attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide field conditionally in tree/list view, you can invisible but that should be fixed for all data not conditionally.

I am not sure but you can achieve this thing by using invisible with context.

Example :

```
<field name="department_id" invisible="context.get('invisible_department', True)"/>
```

Comment: this will hide the column in the tree view